# how to overwrite blank values in a table column with a new value with a new insert statement

Tags: jquery, html, mysql, sql, forms

i have a table that looks like

```
habits proffesion taste attitude geography 
movies bussiness drink motivate rural
```

Now I accept values for these from the FORM tag in html and later insert them into the database with the code,

`insert into rules values('"+hab+"','"+att+"','"+tas+"','"+mor+"','"+eco+"')`

If suppose in the FORM element i enter values for first three columns and press submit, then the values in the table will be for eg:-
**skipping doctor eat (blank) (blank**)

and after another insert statement with all values provided the table becomes,
`skipping doctor eat (blank) (blank)`

```
jumping science veg sleep urban
```

is there a way for the above two rows to be like,

```
skipping doctor eat sleep urban  
jumping science veg (blank) (blank)
```

I mean to say can anyone write a code in jsp that identifies any blank coloumn in the last row and if there are, then replace that blank with the value of the new INSERT statement of that same colum. This is to make the table look without blank spaces
well rather than modifying the table i found it to be easy to do in the HTML page where i amtrying to avoid the spaces being displayed as the options with OPTION tag. the code is

```js
<% for(int i=0;i<a1.size();i++)
           {
                  if(a1.get(i)!=" ")
           %>
                  <option><%= a1.get(i)%></option>
           
           <%}%>
```

in the if condition i tried using '', ' ', "", " ", NULL, null but all these are not working and in the drop down i am still getting those blank options.the dropdown looks like this,
**riding

(blank space)

jumping

cycling**

Comment: First I want to say, this is very badly formatted, I am going to try and see if I can re-formate it, so that you have a better chance of getting this answer answered

Comment: very sorry for the presentation. I am not well equipped with the editing features of stack overflow editor and i am bound by limited time for a solution. pls help

Comment: All good, I fixed it for you, and I am going to answer it for you as well. As what I understand from the question, you want in general that say I forgot to fill in the last row it fetches the next row and inserts that last row in there. See my answer

Comment: So you want the javascript code? that takes the array?

It's honestly really easy once you get the JSON decoded (that is the best way to do this), i'll try to post another answer to outline how you do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going on your edited answer you want Javascript code?

There are a number of steps you need to do.

1) AJAX request the data from the PHP (yep that's the only way I know how to do this in all javascript)

2) JSON.parse - use that to turn the JSON into Array for javascript. *https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse*

3) when you get the the field that is NULL then do an if statement like below.

```
if(result['select_drop_down'] == 'NULL'){
<option value="default" disabled selected>PLEASE SELECT</option>
}
```

Then for the rest of them to the else statement and match it to the other options.

I would of posted some old code that I created when I was doing a booking system for work, but I can't locate it at this time. If you have any questions please comment below.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can get your newly inserted ID, check if row with (ID-1) has blank values, and if so update it with the current values of ID and update the values of ID to be blank. 
However this seems like a very silly thing to do, you would be ruining your table. 
The rows will not contain the original information. Why do you want to do that?

EDIT: 
If you just want to have some value there for the dropdown select menus, you can just add some default value in the script where you form your queries. 
Check if a parameter is blank, and if it is assign it to be "---" or "please select" or some such, and input it like that.

Comment: well this table has no logical relation between the attributes of a single row. Here what matters more is no blanks in the columns. That is particularly because these values are displayed as options in the SELECT and OPTION tags in html. So if i have spaces in the table then even the dropdown in the HTML page shows those blanks as options for selection. That is the main issue

Comment: @nagrajh Thats easy to fix, make the default value in the database NULL, and then in your script if NULL make it ---PLEASE SELECT---.

Thats how all business do it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is the answer to my comment and your questions

> All good, I fixed it for you, and I am going to answer it for you as
>   well. As what I understand from the question, you want in general that
>   say I forgot to fill in the last row it fetches the next row and
>   inserts that last row in there. See my answer –  RussellHarrower

First to do this you want to use Javascript or PHP? It's clean which one you are using.

If you are using PHP it's easy.

The code would look *something* like this - you will have to change it to fit you needs.

But in basic terms, what you need to do, is keep a tally of the row ID (this is not the row ID that is in the table) like the following.

**First get your MYSQL result to return as array or JSON**

Second you will need to be able to read that array like the following - please note I have use an example not directly related to your question, but I hope you understand what I am writing.

```
<?php
$myResults = Array(IN HERE IS YOUR RESULT FROM MYSQL);
$i=0;
foreach($myResult as $results)
{
$a = $i++;
print $result[$i]['name'];
print $result[$i]['lastname'];
print $result[$a]['food'];
$i++;
}
?>
```

I really don't know if the above is what you are looking for, but you will then be able to write your insert script using that loop function.

Let me know if I understood correctly.